# data could not be loaded into SQLite database from webserver

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, webserver

Hi am having a problem while am fetching Data from a web server and insert them direct into SQLite database but first i need to check if the data are not already their in SQLite but am having this issue.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.s

my codes are as below:

Codes for background class to fetch Data are below I try to specify only method to add the returned data into SQLite

```
    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    try {
        DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper(ctx);
        boolean test;
        for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
            Log.i("group", data.get(j));

                if(dbHelper.checkGroupId(DataId.get(j))==false)
                {
                    //now data can be added
                    test=dbHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(DataId.get(j),data.get(j),grpName.get(j),"no");
                    if(test)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Data  Added "+data.get(j),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //notify gui
                        showNotification();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Data not Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }




        }
        dbHelper.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**and Here are codes that add data into SQLite database**

```
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table if not exists groups(groupId varchar(50),groupName text,targetAmount text,fetched varchar(10))";
public static final String DROP_TABLE="drop table if exists "+DbContract.TABLE_NAME;


    public DbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DbContract.DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}


    public boolean saveToLocalDatabase(String groupId,String groupName,String targetAmount,String fetched)
{
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DbContract.GROUP_ID,groupId);
    contentValues.put(DbContract.GROUP_NAME,groupName);
    contentValues.put(DbContract.TARGET_AMOUNT,targetAmount);
    contentValues.put(DbContract.FETCHED,fetched);
    //now add data to databse
    long result=database.insert(DbContract.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result==-1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This function check if data is not already in database and Here is Where the error is shown to be from the backgroundTask class

```
    //function to check if the given id is available
public boolean checkGroupId(String groupId)
{
    String query="select * from groups where groupId='"+groupId+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();;
    //create cursor to return data
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(query,null);
    int counter=0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        counter=counter+1;
    }
    //check counters returned
    if(counter>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**THIS MY OUTPUT TERMINAL LOG DATA WHERE THE ERROR IS**

```
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
```

08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at info.androidhive.uplus.DbHelper.checkGroupId(DbHelper.java:165)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at info.androidhive.uplus.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:136)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at info.androidhive.uplus.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:28)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
08-07 04:14:58.075 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-07 04:14:58.076 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
08-07 04:14:58.076 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
08-07 04:14:58.076 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-07 04:14:58.076 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-07 04:14:58.076 28663-28663/info.androidhive.uplus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

PLEASE ANYONE WHO COULD I WISH HE/SHE COULD
THANKS

Comment: Making sure the "context" your initializing your DBHelper with is not null is good advice.  ALSO: check out this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#tutorial-using-sqlite

Answer (score 3):

Check you Context in the params, make sure it's not null.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.s

The above error is because your context is null.

```
DbHelper dbHelper=new DbHelper(ctx);// ctx should not be null
```

Comment: @realfair: if the "answer is helpful", then a) upvote it (if you haven't already), and b) accept it (if it resolved the problem).